# How can I create an application that allows me to open up VS Code anywhere for quick editing purposes?

Tags: visual-studio-code

There are lots of **pop-up windows**-type applications for vim ([vim-anywhere](https://github.com/cknadler/vim-anywhere)) and emacs ([emacs-anywhere](https://github.com/zachcurry/emacs-anywhere)/[emacs-everywhere](https://github.com/tecosaur/emacs-everywhere)). However, I can't find a similar alternative for VSCode or think of a good way to achieve this in VSCode. Is this possible? Or is this already implemented in some ways?

To add more content, I use LaTeX with VSCode, and I'm trying to recreate this functionality: [adding text](https://castel.dev/post/lecture-notes-2/#adding-text) from the blog post but with VSCode. See gif (also from Gilles Castel):

[image]

Comment: This might be a question to ask on [tex.se]

Comment: I believe this is for VSCode specifically since what I want is the pop-up window for VSCode.

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't appropriate here, but there is a whole Stack dedicated to LaTex who might be able to help you. It'd be worth a look, if you haven't already.

Comment: I see your point. I will take a look there.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is even possible with [custom editors](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/custom-editors) or [notebooks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks) due to the lack of custom modal support. The closest thing is probably the [input box](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#window.showInputBox) widget were you can ask for user input and process it to your needs or use a web editor and use CSS and div elements to mimic modals.

Comment: @RomanVottner Sounds like this is impossible for now : (